# JSON RPC получить последний event

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, json-rpc

вот допустим контракт на обмен - https://etherscan.io/address/0x49b19581d9d1d24ffdffaf7eece27712fbea2d8b, мне нужно получить данные о последнем ивенте Sync и Transfer. Есть timestamp вызова этих событий, он привязан к функции getReserves. Как-нибудь возможно получить по timestamp номер блока? тогда по нему уже можно будет узнать и о последних ивентах

Answer (score 0):

Если нет желания "вручную" сканировать все новые блоки на предмет включенных в них событий (eth_getLogs), можно использовать функции eth_newFilter и eth_getFilterChanges, задав адрес контракта в качестве фильтра.

А почему не сохранять сразу номер блока (block.number)?